# How to access the hardware layer when building a NativeScript plugin?

Tags: plugins, nativescript, native

I'm trying to build a plugin to access the camera and I'm not sure how to access the hardware. When I import android, it says that there is no camera2 of undefined.

```
import { Common } from './CameraPlugin.common';
import { android } from 'tns-core-modules/application';
export class CameraPlugin extends Common {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    public takePicture() {
        const cameraManager = new android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager();
        cameraManager.openCamera();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be running Android API level 21 or up, you are not suppose to create an instance but retrieve it from system services - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#CAMERA_SERVICE

Answer (score 1):

NativeScript has native access to the Java/Kotlin (on Android) and ObjC/Swift (on iOS) devices with some minor limitations. (1)(2)

First you don't want/need to import "android" from anything; it is a valid global on all Android devices.   So all you have to do is do `android.` (or `java.`, or whatever namespace you need access too.)   The import you did actually just hid the `android` global and replaced it with a different object which for sure doesn't have it.

One word of caution; unless you have installed the platform typescript typings, your editor will NOT know what `android.`, `android.hardware.`, etc are. When you go to actually run it; NativeScript will know what it is and use it just fine.

If you want your editor to know what it is, you need to install the platform typings:
`npm i --save-dev tns-platform-declarations` and you can read how to set them up here: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/tree/master/tns-platform-declarations

**NativeScript documentation related to how the engine accesses the native code.**

(1) - https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/overview

(2) - https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/Overview

Comment: Great answer. I see under the global 'android' there are many references to camera or cameras. How do I know which one to use? The documentation is a little sparse. For example, do I need to get a camera manager or just under hardware etc.

Comment: Well you basically need to program the code like you are doing it in Java.   So if the Android documentation says you need to access "blah" from the the "com.object.somename" namespace; you would type "com.object.somename.blah".   As for Camera / Camera2 according to the docs at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary you need to get the CameraManager and then request a device.